# How to reduce space between 2 nodes that are above other node?

Tags: latex, tikz

How can I position Variable 2 and Variable 3 nodes so that they are closer together and above Variable 1?

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode, text width=7cm,minimum height=1cm] (v1){Variable 1};
\node[mynode,above left= 2cm of v1, text width = 4cm, minimum height = 1cm](v2) {Variable 2};
\node[mynode,above right= 2cm of v1, text width=4cm, minimum height = 1cm] (v3){Variable 3};

\draw[-latex] (v2.south) -- (v1.north);
\draw[-latex] (v3.south) -- (v1.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

What I get with the above code:

[image]

I would like them to be positioned like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack: `xshift` the nodes to where you want them to be:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode, text width=7cm,minimum height=1cm] (v1){Variable 1};
\node[mynode,above left= 2cm of v1, text width = 4cm, minimum height = 1cm,xshift=3cm](v2) {Variable 2};
\node[mynode,above right= 2cm of v1, text width=4cm, minimum height = 1cm,xshift=-3cm] (v3){Variable 3};

\draw[-latex] (v2.south) -- (v1.north);
\draw[-latex] (v3.south) -- (v1.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]